# How do I know which element was clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, event-bubbling

I'm attempting the surprisingly difficult task of finding out which element was clicked. I have these functions from Head First AJAX:

```
function getActivatedObject(e) {
  var obj;
  if (!e) {
    obj = window.event.srcElement;
  } else if (e.srcElement) {
    obj = e.srcElement;
  } else {
    obj = e.target;
  }
  return obj;
}

function addEventHandler(obj, eventName, handler) {
  if (document.attachEvent) {
    obj.attachEvent("on" + eventName, handler);
  } else if (document.addEventListener) {
    obj.addEventListener(eventName, handler, false);
  }
}
```

And my code:

```
mainPane = document.getElementById("mainDiv");
contactPane = document.getElementById("contactDiv");
addEventHandler(mainPane, "click", openFunction);
addEventHandler(contactPane, "click", openFunction);

function openFunction(e) {
  var me = getActivatedObject(e);
  //Some other stuff
}
```

Unfortunately, the me variable sometimes refers to the div, but it sometimes refers to the image inside the div. Even though the image has no onclick function or any other kind of event! So how can I get the div that triggered the event?

Comment: I'd strongly encourage you to consider using a framework like jQuery which would make a task like this trivial.

Comment: @michaeltomer, so this task is complicated and involved without a framework?

Comment: It's not complicated and involved, it's just more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Which browser(s) are you seeing this behavior in?

Comment: You can test the obj.tagName - if it is img, you can look to see if obj.parentNode is a div you can use

Comment: @Matt, I first saw it with Firebug, but if I add "alert(me.id);" then it shows the id for the image in IE and Chrome, too.

Comment: In FireBug and Chrome's dev tools, you can explore/inspect all of the properties of an object by using console.log(obj), and then expanding the resulting tree.  This may help you understand what properties are there, and what their values are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dealing with [Event bubbling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html).

Basically, your click on a child element bubbles up through all of that child's parents; if those parents have a click handler bound to them, it will execute.

In pseudocode: you can see what element your current target is, and if it's not a DIV, you know that you need to look for that element's parent.

Using your example, it would look something like this (simplified a bit for your example; in reality, you'd need something much more robust):

```
function getActivatedObject(e) {
  var obj;
  if (!e) {
    obj = window.event.srcElement;
  } else if (e.srcElement) {
    obj = e.srcElement;
  } else {
    obj = e.target;
  }

  // Images are direct children of our DIV. If our source element was an img, we should
  // fetch its parent
  if(obj.tagName.toLowerCase() === "img"){
      obj = obj.parentNode;
  }

  return obj;
}
```

Note that this will work for your example only; in the real world, you would likely need to iterate back up the DOM tree, comparing `parentNodes` with the elements you are interested in until you've found what you're looking for.

Most JavaScript libraries abstract this away for you (jQuery, for example, sets a `currentTarget` property of all Events it dispatches that refers to the element you need, encapsulating all the traversal work for you). Makes it easier, but it's not too terrible a job to write that yourself and I'd argue against including the overhead of an entire JavaScript library if that's all you need to do. :-)

EDIT: Totally destroyed my formatting! D'oh!

Comment: Thank you! Thank you especially for helping me understand what's going on instead of just doing it for me. Instead of your if statement, I used a while loop that keeps going until it finds a div. It works great. :-D

Comment: Great! While loop is a good way to do it, but make sure to bail out if you ever hit the BODY or DOCUMENT tags, just in case something went wrong; otherwise, infinite loop!