# Button onClick doesn't work if it is inside of DIV in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, event-handling

I have a div like as :

```
<div id="specific">
<table cellpadding="2" border="0">
<tr><td>Choose category</td><td><select id="list_categories" runat="server"></select></td><td><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="list_categories" runat="server" Display="Static" ErrorMessage="Select category" ID="verify_category"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td></tr>
<tr><td>Link name : </td><td><asp:TextBox ID="link_name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td><td><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="link_name" runat="server" Display="Static" ErrorMessage="Provide a name for link" ID="verify_link_name"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td></tr>
<tr><td>Link url : </td><td><asp:TextBox ID="link_url" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td><td><asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="verify_url" runat="server" ControlToValidate="link_url" Display="Static" ErrorMessage="Invalid link. Must be as http://www.stabiplan.com" ValidationExpression="^http\://[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/\S*)?$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator></td></tr>
<tr><td>Link description</td><td><asp:TextBox ID="link_descr" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td><td><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="link_descr" runat="server" ID="verify_descr" Display="Static" ErrorMessage="Provide a link description"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><center><asp:Button runat="server" ID="add_link_process" Text="Add link" OnClick="add_link_function" /></center></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

and the function from CodeBehind.cs

```
protected void add_link_function( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
         BusinessLayerArcht layer = LoadDataFromBL();
         if ( layer.add_link( link_name.Text, link_url.Text, link_descr.Text, list_categories.Value.ToString() ) ) {
            messages.Text = "Link added successfully";
            LoadTree( tree );
         } else {
            messages.Text = "Link could not be added !";
         }
      }
```

When I click on the button, nothing happens. Why ?

If I remove DIV block and let the code inside the `<table>`, button click event works.

Thank you

Comment: Is there any javascript/css associated with that `div#specific`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I highly doubt it has anything to do with the div element. Usually, when a button does nothing it's because validation is preventing the postback. To test this, set the `CausesValidation` property to false on the Button and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding a breakpoint to the `add_link_function` method to check whether its being triggered at all?

---

Regarding your validation issue, you can add `ValidationGroup` to your Validation controls as well as your `Button`. This way, only validation controls with a matching group name as the triggered button, will be actioned.

Comment: Yes I tried adding breakpoint and that button onClick function couldn't be triggered...Why ?  How I said, if I let the code inside the table, everything is OK... Is something with DIV

Comment: thank for the trick with ValidationGroup. The first problem is still exists

Answer (score 1):

may you have to change the property of button " UseSubmitBehavior " to false

Answer (score 0):

This is is a total guess, but it's possible the 'div' is sitting on top of your table and preventing the click getting to the button, you could try some Javascript code like this -

```
function getActivatedObject(e) {
  var obj;
  if (!e) {
    obj = window.event.srcElement;
  } else if (e.srcElement) {
    obj = e.srcElement;
  } else {
    obj = e.target;
  }
  return obj;
}

function addEventHandler(obj, eventName, handler) {
  if (document.attachEvent) {
    obj.attachEvent("on" + eventName, handler);
  } else if (document.addEventListener) {
    obj.addEventListener(eventName, handler, false);
  }
}
```

to work out which element was getting the click event.

Code from - [How do I know which element was clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833708/how-do-i-know-which-element-was-clicked)

Answer (score 0):

In the properties of that button, set OnClientClick as the name of the function you are calling on "onClick".
It worked for me.